Grid data to Pandas
I have developed a code that successfully creates a grid, allows the user to input data, and saves it in a list. However, when I press the button to save the grid data to pandas, an error occurs:
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\mainfol\mfatt\jeadomgrod.py", line 43, in topamda
    df.at[i, j] = float(text1.get())
    ^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'at'

import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

titles = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6','A7', 'A8','A9','A10']
cells = []
for column, title in enumerate(titles):
    # add column header labels
    tk.Label(frame, text=title).grid(row=0, column=column)
    cells. Append([])
    for row in range(5):  # add 5 rows of Entry widgets
        text1 = tk.Entry(frame)
        # row here is offset by +1 because the titles are using row 0
        text1.grid(column=column, row=row + 1)
        text1.insert(0, row)
        cells[column].append(text1)


def topamda():
    masterlines = []
    df = pd
    for i, row in enumerate(cells):
        for j, text1 in enumerate(row):
            df.at[i, j] = float(text1.get())
            print(df)

button = tk.Button(root,    text="Data to Pandas DF" , command = topamda)

button.pack()


df = pd this isn't how you create a dataframe. It's how you alias pandas as "df". You need to create a DataFrame object with pd.DataFrame(); consider reading the DataFrame documentation to better understand its usage.

As said in comment, you need to use df = pd.DataFrame() to create an empty dataframe:
def topamda():
    # create an empty dataframe with given column names
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=titles)
    # add values to dataframe column by column from cells
    for col, entries in zip(titles, cells):
        df[col] = [float(e.get()) for e in entries]
    print(df)

Output of print(df):
    A1   A2   A3   A4   A5   A6   A7   A8   A9  A10
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
3  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
4  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0


There are a couple of problems with your code:

cells.append has a capital "A" (it should be lowercase)
you didn't actually create a dataframe in the topamda function
root.mainloop() is never called to keep the window open

I corrected the code for you:
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

titles = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6','A7', 'A8','A9','A10']
cells = []
for column, title in enumerate(titles):
    tk.Label(frame, text=title).grid(row=0, column=column)
    cells.append([])
    for row in range(5): 
        text1 = tk.Entry(frame)
        text1.grid(column=column, row=row + 1)
        text1.insert(0, row)
        cells[column].append(text1)

def topamda():
    data = []
    for column in cells:
        column_data = [float(entry.get()) for entry in column]
        data.append(column_data)
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
    df.columns = titles 
    print(df)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Data to Pandas DF", command=topamda)
button.pack()

root.mainloop() 

